# Move ball inside border of Div

Tags: jquery, html, setinterval

I have looked around examples on how to move a ball using jquery but the examples are not exactly what I am looking for. I simply want to change the ball to move around the inside edges of the div box. So far my ball shoots outside the box and won't loop within the box. Any suggestions?

Main function that should perform this is within my function:

```
function moveMe() {
// Read the current left position of the ball
var currentLeftPos = parseInt($("#ball").css('left'));

// define the new position
var newLeftPos = currentLeftPos + velocity_y;

// If the left position is greater than or equal to the maximum distance allowed or
//   less than or equal to zero, then change the direction.

if( newLeftPos >= maxLeft || newLeftPos <= 0)
    velocity_y *= -1; // multiply the value by -1

// update the position
$("#ball").css('left', newLeftPos + 'px');

var i = 1;
var interval = setInterval( increment, 1000);
$('#sec-played').text(interval);
function increment(){
i = i % 360 + 1;
}
}
```

Here is my full running code: https://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/2511/

new program with update https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/4857/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you handle the boundary condition is not robust.  If the ball finds itself more than `velocity_y` pixels beyond either boundary, then the velocity will just keep reversing on every frame, and the ball will get stuck vibrating in outer space (which you can actually see happening in your demo if you make the window big enough).  A more robust approach would replace your boundary check with

```
if(newLeftPos > maxLeft) velocity_y = -Math.abs(velocity_y);
else if (newLeftPos < 0) velocity_y = +Math.abs(velocity_y);
```

You should also ensure that the velocity can't exceed `(maxLeft-0)`, and for completeness you could also do the arithmetic to make the bounce happen exactly at the boundary (currently the ball will bounce off an indeterminate point slightly beyond the boundary).

As to how the ball is getting so far outside the boundary in the first place, that's due to a fun typecasting bug.  You are initially setting `velocity_y` to the *string* `"5"` (read from a text input) instead of the *number* `5`, and so when you add it to `currentLeftPos` you're getting string addition-- the position becomes `"5"`, then `"55"`, then `"555"`.  At that point you multiply `velocity_y` by -1, causing it to become a number, and the bug disappears.  To fix this, just replace

```
var velocity_y = $('#dy').val();
```

with

```
var velocity_y = $('#dy').val() * 1;
```

and it all works first time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did the corrections you said and did an alert(newLeftPos) to check the increments are working 5 at a time which it does. However, the ball position doesn't change still when it reaches the edge of the div. I simply want the ball to run along the edge. I don't see what is still causing it to not stay inside the box

Comment: If I paste those two changes into your jsFiddle page, it works for me!  (NB I'm removing your original 'if' statement at line 49)

Comment: I posted the new jsfiddle.net . It still doesn't work for me :/

Comment: So weird that the first jsfiddle does in fact work. I copy and pasted that version into my file and ran it but it doesn't work. I don't know why in jsfiddle it works but not when I run it from my file.

Comment: ya I saw that. fixes jsfiddle but when I do that to my "copy and pasted version" it still doesn't stay inside the div. Weirdest thing I have ever seen

Comment: I will just try to figure out why it isn't working. thanks for your help!